# customer-ordering table-sql

Tags: sql

I trying to write the sql query which will give me this output below.  And you can see the tables I have added.   Thanks in advance

Comment: Not a good idea for screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer as per OP**

This will give you only `customer_id` with maximum number of orders. It is bit complex query to form in MySQL due to lack of analytical function. But this should work fine.

```
select t.* from 
    (select o.customer_id,
    count(*) as no_of_orders
    from orders o
    group by o.customer_id) t
where 
t.no_of_orders =
    (
    select max(no_of_orders) from 
        (select o.customer_id,
        count(*) as no_of_orders
        from orders o
        group by o.customer_id
        )t2
    )
```

**See demo here**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18726a/12

**Previous Answer:**

This will work. `Left Join` will make sure to give a count of `0` in case customer does not have any `order`

```
select c.customer_id,count(o.order_id) as NO_OF_ORDERS
from customers c
left join orders o
on c.customer_id=o.customer_id
group by c.customer_id
```

**See demo here**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c19e/4

Comment: Utsav  thanks but,  I need to find number of orders of customers with maximum number of orders.

Comment: @Schecter - Check the updated answer and if it works for you them please accept the answer by clicking on `check` symbol on left of the question.

Comment: Thank you so much Utsav, It is now working. I have also 3 more query I could not write.  Can you also help me for them.

Answer (score 0):

Most dialects of SQL support the ANSI standard row number functions.  You can use them for this purpose.  Note that  `join` is not necessary:

```
select customer_id, cnt
from (select o.customer_id, count(*) as cnt,
             max(count(*)) over () as maxcnt
      from orders o
      group by o.customer_id
     ) o
where cnt = maxcnt;
```